# Bluetooth man in the middle protection in Windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, bluetooth

I'm playing with [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Bluetooth native programming.

I'm successfully pairing my Windows PC with my Android device, but when I'm changing [AUTHENTICATION_REQUIREMENTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee844560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parameter in [BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc766819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function
from  `AUTHENTICATION_REQUIREMENTS::MITMProtectionRequiredGeneralBonding` 
to `AUTHENTICATION_REQUIREMENTS::MITMProtectionRequired` 
my code is "failing" to pair with my Android device.

By "failing" I'm mean that all APIs are return `ERROR_SUCCESS` code and in Android phone my Windows PC appears as "paired", but in my Windows PC the Android device was not added to the Bluetooth devices. Moreover, if I'll try to use my Android phone and connect to my Windows PC, the pairing process will be started again (I guess it is since previously pairing was not completed successfully).

The Windows code is as follows:

```
int Authenticate(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO device)
{
      HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION hAuthentication = nullptr;

      DWORD err = BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx(&device, 
                                                       &hAuthentication,
                                                       &::AuthenticationCallbackStatic, 
                                                       nullptr);
      if (ERROR_SUCCESS != err) { return -1; }

      // Changing last parameter to MITMProtectionRequired will cause to pairing 
      // complete unsuccessfully
      err = BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx(nullptr, 
                                          nullptr, 
                                          &device, 
                                          nullptr,
                                          MITMProtectionRequiredGeneralBonding); 
      if (ERROR_SUCCESS != err) { return -1; }

      return 0;
}
```

Any idea why this parameter is causing pairing to fail?

Answer (score 0):

There is a  difference between "Pairing" and "Bonding". 
Pairing is generation of a shared secret(key) between two devices that may be used during authentication of the current session.

If the key is stored, the two devices are bonded.

MITMProtectionRequired as per MSDN, is  "MITM requirement for Authentication" So I understand it means just pairing and not bonding.
That's how you see ERROR_SUCCESS but the key is not stored. So pairing is required for subsequent connections.